# .Net CSVHelper accessing all of the records

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am a bit confused with how to access all of the records.  It will not let me run a foreach() through the items and it only returns the first one as an object.  I am aware it says this in the documentation.  But I am not sure what to do about it.

```
The GetRecords<T> method will return an IEnumerable<T> that will yield 
records. What this means is that only a single record is returned at a time 
as you iterate the records. That also means that only a small portion of the 
file is read into memory. Be careful though. If you do anything that 
executes a LINQ projection, such as calling .ToList(), the entire file will 
be read into memory. CsvReader is forward only, so if you want to run any 
LINQ queries against your data, you'll have to pull the whole file into 
memory. Just know that is what you're doing.
```

Here is my code

```
protected void WatcherCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Watcher Created");
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(_watchedFolder, "*.csv");
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
            {
                try
                {
                    csv.Read();
                    var records = csv.GetRecord<InputCsv>();


                }
                catch (CsvHelper.HeaderValidationException exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(exception);
                    throw;
                }




            }
        }
    }
```

The records is the supposed IEnumerable..  I eventually want to use the object o parse it into json using Newtonsoft.Json

It doesn't even offer me a .ToList() option after the csv.GetRecords();

Comment: I would guess that, the fact the function is called `GetRecord` means that it retrieves one row from the csv file.

Comment: Dangit. You are correct.  It was supposed to be GetRecords.  Thank you. I thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: As a side note, it appears you are trying to use the file watcher.  Be aware, that it will only tell you a file has been created.  If you have a huge file, then you may get a notification that a file is available, but in reality, it hasn't finished copying yet, so you will get an exception when you try and open it.  Oh, and `FileSystemEventArgs ` should contain the name of the file that has changed, no need to do another directory scan.

Comment: @Neil Thanks,  I am mainly using it to see if a csv is dropped into a folder.  I then want the file to be sent as json using Http to another API.  What other alternative would you use for this situation?

Comment: No need for alternatives.   I have a simple function which tries to open the file in write mode, if it throws an exception, sleep for 500ms and try and open it again (repeat as necessary).   Eventually it will open, then you can process it as you are already doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a missing letter on the function call:

```
var records = csv.GetRecord<InputCsv>();
```

You should be calling `GetRecords` - note the extra s.

```
var records = csv.GetRecords<InputCsv>();
```